# Latent space image interpolation

Tags: image, interpolation, encoder, decoder

Can someone tell me how (or the name of it, so that I could look it up) I can implement this interpolation effect? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36lE9tV9vm0&t=3010s&frags=pl%2Cwn

I tried to use r = r+dr, g = g+dr and b = b+db for the RGB values in each iteration, but it looks way too simple compared to the effect from the video.

Comment: It used to be called morphing. Here's a paper which examines some algorithms;  https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jacobliu/368Report/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Can someone tell me how I can implement this interpolation effect?
>
>   (or the name of it, so that I could look it up)...*"

It's not actually a named interpolation effect. It *appears* to interpolate but really it's just realtime updated variations of some fictional facial "features" (the hair, eyes, nose, etc are **synthesized** pixels taking *hints* from a library/database of possible matching feature types).

For this technique they used Neural Networks to do a process similar to *DFT Image Reconstruction*. You'll be modifying the image data in *Frequency* domain (with u,v), not *Time* domain (using x,y).

You can read about it at this PDF: 
https://research.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/pubs/2017-10_Progressive-Growing-of/karras2018iclr-paper.pdf

The (Python) source code: 
https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans

For ideas, on Youtube you can look up:

- `DFT image reconstruction` (there's a good example with b/w Nicholas Cage photo reconstructed in stages. Loud music warning).
- `Image Synthesis` with neural networks (one clip had salternative shoe and hand-bag designs (item photos) being "synthesized" by an N.N. after it analyzed features from other existing catalogue photos as "inspiration".
- `Image Enhancement Super Resolution using neural networks` This method is closest to answering your question. One  example has very low-res blurry pixelated image in b/w. Cannot tell if boy or girl. During a test, The network synthesizes various higher quality face images that it thinks is the correct match for the testing input.

After understanding what/how they're achieve it, you could think of shortcuts to get similar effect without needing networks eg: only using regular pixel editing functions.

Comment: So the magick is simply to use three dimensional data stored in multiresolution format, matching the low resolution of the data first and from there on interpolating into the most probable versions of the higher  resolution data? What I don't understand is, why it isn't mentioned this way in all the papers available, so much confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in another video, it is called "latent space interpolation", it has to be applied on the compressed images. If I have image A and the next image is image B, I have first to encode A and B, use the interpolation on the encoded data and finally decode the resulted image.

Comment: Interesting. Is this compressing to Jpeg? What happens if and A and B don't have same matching number of bytes after compression? Otherwise seems like cool idea. Jpeg transforms data into frequency domain (less numbers/bytes but can later reconstruct visually similar data) using DCT method (not DFT).

Comment: I guess a simple Haar-Wavelet compression is enough, the matrix without further entropy encoding. The matrix will have several zero values, this explains why the interpolation looks like the objects are moving and transforming while they move and form the new object, since the compressed image filters (by zeroing them) out the low entropy pixels, that fill the space between the relevant/high energy-state objects-pixels.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, I found out that this kind of interpolation effect can be easily implemented for 3d image data. That is if the image data is available in a normalized and at 3d origin centred way, like for example in a unit sphere around the origin and the data of each faceimage is inside that unit sphere. Having the data of two images stored this way the interpolation can be calculated by taking the differences of rays going through the origin center and through each area of the sphere at some desired resolution.